# RHEL7 で NIC の名前を eno1 から従来の eth0 に変更するには？

Tags: linux, rhel

RHEL7 でネットワークを設定すると、デフォルトではインターフェース名として "eno1", "eno2" などの名前が付けられますが、これを従来までの "eth0", "eth1" に変更するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

#### 環境

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
- FUJITSU PRIMERGY RX2530 M5

#### 試したこと

- GRUB の設定 (ブートパラメータ) に以下を追加して grub.cfg を再生成
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0`
- `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` 以下の設定ファイル(`ifcfg-*`)をリネームし、ファイル内の記述も修正

  ```
  # mv ifcfg-eno1 ifcfg-eth0
  # vi ifcfg-eth0              ## DEVICEやNAMEをeth0に変更
  ```
- 上記設定の変更後、OSを再起動しても eth0 は利用できない状態です。

**参考にした記事:**
[CentOS 7のネットワーク管理基礎 (前編)](https://thinkit.co.jp/story/2014/12/25/5412)
[CentOS 7のネットワーク管理基礎 (後編)](https://thinkit.co.jp/story/2015/01/08/5446)
[CentOS7系でNICの命名規則を変更する際の注意点について](https://www.denet.ad.jp/technology/2017/12/centos7nic.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今回は以下の手順で設定変更を行うことができました。

**変更手順**

- 変更したいアダプタ `eno1` に割り当てられたMACアドレスを確認しておく (`ether` に続く文字列)。

  ```
  # ifconfig eno1
  eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
  ...
          ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
  ```
- 設定ファイルをリネーム

  ```
  # cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
  # mv ifcfg-eno1 ifcfg-eth0
  ```
- `ifcfg-eth0` をエディタで開き、`DEVICE=` の名前を `eth0` に変更。もし存在しない場合は `DEVICE=` と `HWADDR=` の行を追記しておく。

  ```
  # vi ifcfg-eth0
  ...
  DEVICE=eth0
  NAME=eth0
  HWADDR=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
  ...
  ```
- 設定変更後、OSを再起動して反映されているかを確認。

  ```
  # ifconfig
  eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
  ...
  ```